# Can this be DRYed up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, dry

I was wondering if there's a good way to DRY this up.

```
if session[:working_post].nil?
  @post = Post.new
else
  @post = Post.new(session[:working_post])
  session[:working_post] = nil
end
```

Maybe something like

```
@post = Post.new(||= session[:working_post])
```

Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would this work?

```
@post = Post.new(session.delete(:working_post) || {})
```

Answer (score 1):

If `session[:working_post]` is a hash you could do this:

```
@post = Post.new(session[:working_post] || {})
```